# Why is my screen reader reading lines multiple times?

Tags: html, angularjs, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have an HTML structure like

```html
<button ng-disabled="vm.updating" ng-click="doSomething()" class="something" type="submit" aria-label="average score">
  
<span ng hide="hideConditional()" class="font-white">score</span>
<span ng-show="showConditional()" class="font-white">
  <span class="grey"></span>
  <span>scoring</span>
</span>
</button>
```

When I turn on the screen reader, it reads **average score score scoring button** multiple times and then again **score scoring**, but I only want it to read whatever text I write into the button and ignore child elements text like everything which is inside spans or any control underneath the button. But I am not able to ignore the rest of the content.

I tried to use `aria-hidden` on each `span` but no avail.

Can anyone please correct me? What am I missing here? How can make the screen reader ignore text from elements inside `button` and make it only read text which is set on the button itself?

Comment: Do you have a URL with this functioning? When I [made a pen](http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/YWxqYv), all I get is "average score button" on focus and (obviously) nothing on click/press. Since the AT reads the rendered HTML and not the `ng-aria` bits on their own, this is impossible properly debug otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

```
<div class="" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" > </div>
```

It worked very well for me.